# Google Sheet Query + Countif + Condition Question [2 condition?]

Tags: google-sheets

I want to populate how many counts that the company appeared on specific week of the month on a year to year basis and I'm having difficulty for that. I'm sorry.

I want to populate how many times each companies occurred or counted depending on the week chosen in the dashboard sheet. I'm sorry English is not my first language.

I use query formula to list and count each companies but when changing the week it does not factor my query I'm unsure what to do.

I was able to do array formula on the right part of the sheet once you've checked the link below but I think it will factor out if 2 companies have the same highest count as it will only output 1 text which is why I have thought of using query to list all companies and how many times they count depending on week chosen but seems the query that I have inputted populates all the data that is in the Dashboard sheet.

I hope someone can help me.

Here is my demo sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMoWww9sGxyIC7LLJWBsNRMXN8a7mme1RCT2_IYIXCM/edit#gid=1696267131

How to add the year condition then week?

Be able to condition the google sheet to auto populate the sheet on a year + week basis

Comment: Can you ***manually*** enter and showcase the ideal expected output you wish to see in your test sheet?!

Comment: The ideal scenario is that the 

I can choose a year. either 2023 or 2024 then it auto populates in the dashboard tab.

I can just make a copy of the sheet itself then do not add a year as an option but I want to know if it is possible for it to have a 2023 or 2024 as an option for data that can be pulled in the dashboard.

as for example in this current google sheet that I have. I put another september raw file that is also Week 38 but year 2024 it populates even though the year is still 2023 in the dashboard as I'm unable to include it in my current formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I've added the `year` component to your existing query formula. do test it out:*

```js
=QUERY(Database!$B:$H,"select B, count(B) 
where F=" & C5 &" AND H=" & C2 &"
group by B 
order by count(B) DESC 
label B 'List of Companies', count(B) 'Counts'",-1)
```